# MongoDB query to capitalise first letter in existing database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, mongo-collection

Here is the problem,

> I want to capitalise the first letter of a name in my existing
>   database, just wanted to know if there is any query so that i can make
>   it possbile.

what i want -- in my database so many names is in unformatted ways.. like lucy, Sean, jon and so on. i want to make them in a formatted ways like. Lucy. Sean, Jon. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your effort. What you have tried so far to solve your problem, so that you can get help or suggestions.

Comment: tried https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/

Comment: but didnt work for me

Comment: because i want to make the first letter in a capital form

Comment: You want to update in the data base with capitalized name, right?

Comment: @titi23 yes.. but not in full capital words.. but in a standard form (Only capitalized the first letter of the fisrtname collection) for example, not in JON but in Jon

Comment: Try [bulk update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910462/how-to-do-string-in-proper-case-using-mongodb

Comment: it wont work..! bacause it will find a single word and update it with capital for example it will make my name Aman like AmAn

Comment: There is a solution proposed in above link. try that too

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906508/change-capital-letters-in-mongo-to-camel-casing/41906522#41906522

Answer (score 1):

it may not be the best solution. 
the only hiccup in below suggestion is to get "3" of $substr:["$name1",1,**3**] dynamically. 
but gives you a start?

```
db.toupper.aggregate([{$project:{name:{$concat:[{$toUpper:{$substr:["$name1",0,1]}},{$substr:["$name1",1,**3**]}]}}}])
```

below is the result

```
 db.toupper.find()

 "_id" : ObjectId("5767ca0badb381a5cc0d19cd"), "name1" : "lean" }
 "_id" : ObjectId("5767ca3aadb381a5cc0d19ce"), "name1" : "lean" }

 db.toupper.aggregate([{$project:{name:{$concat:[{$toUpper:{$substr:["$name1",0,1]}},{$substr:["$name1",1,3]}]}}}])

 "_id" : ObjectId("5767ca0badb381a5cc0d19cd"), "name" : "Lean" }
 "_id" : ObjectId("5767ca3aadb381a5cc0d19ce"), "name" : "Lean" }
```