# How to capitalize first letter of each word in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This should be a quick 2 minute find, but i'm searching for an hour and can't find any solution.

> How can i **capitalize first letter of each word** of the `username` field?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5908288bfbce59540a67fa11"),
    "username" : "JOHN DOE"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5908288bfbce59540a67fa12"),
    "username" : "jane doe"
}
```

Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919820/mongodb-query-to-capitalise-first-letter-in-existing-database) that i don't really understand, but it doesn't work: `Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms`

```
db.getCollection('test').toupper.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                username: {
                    $concat: [{
                        $toUpper: { $substr: ["$username", 0, 1] }
                    }, { $substr: ["$username", 1, 3] }]
                }
            }
        }])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
var map = {
    "$map": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$username", " " ] },
        "as": "name",
        "in": {                                                                             
            "$concat": [
                { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": ["$$name", 0, 1] } }, 
                {                                                           
                    "$substrCP": [
                        "$$name",
                        1,
                        { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "$$name" }, 1 ]}
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "username": {
                "$concat": [
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 0] },
                    " ",
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 1] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

---

To capitalize the first letter of each word in a string, you first need to split the string by a given delimiter using the **[`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/#exp._S_split)** operator, in this instance the delimiter would be a space:

**Example**

```
{ "$split": [ "jane doe", " " ] }
```

**Results**

```
[ "jane", "doe" ]
```

---

Next step is to use the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator on the result array above and for each element in the array apply the **[`$toUpper`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/#exp._S_toUpper)** transformation on a substring with **[`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/#exp._S_substrCP)** as well as the concat process with **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)**  to return a transformed array.

Within the transformation, you would need to get the first letter in a given word, transform that letter to uppercase and then concatenate the rest of the string.

For the first part, the transformation follows:

**Example**

```
{ "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": ["jane", 0, 1] } }
```

**Results**

```
"J"
```

And for the remainder of the string

**Example**

```
{                                                                           
    "$substrCP": [
        "jane",
        1,
        { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "jane" }, 1 ]}
    ] 
}
```

**Results**

```
"ane"
```

---

### Concatenation

**Example**

```
{                                                                           
    $concat: [
        { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": ["jane", 0, 1] } }, 
        {                                                           
            "$substrCP": [
                "jane",
                1,
                { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "jane" }, 1 ]}
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

**Results**

```
"Jane"
```

---

### Mapping to elements in an array

Using the above in **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)**:

**Example**

```
{
    "$map": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "jane doe", " " ] },
        "as": "name",
        "in": {                                                                             
            "$concat": [
                { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": ["$$name", 0, 1] } }, 
                {                                                           
                    "$substrCP": [
                        "jane",
                        1,
                        { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "$$name" }, 1 ]}
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
[ "Jane", "Doe" ]
```

You can then use the above as an expression for the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator and use the **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)** again as:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
        "username": {
            "$concat": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 0] },
                " ",
                { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 1] }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Your final aggregate operation becomes:

```
var map = {
    "$map": {
        "input": { "$split": [ "$username", " " ] },
        "as": "name",
        "in": {                                                                             
            "$concat": [
                { "$toUpper": { "$substrCP": ["$$name", 0, 1] } }, 
                {                                                           
                    "$substrCP": [
                        "$$name",
                        1,
                        { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "$$name" }, 1 ]}
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "username": {
                "$concat": [
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 0] },
                    " ",
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [map, 1] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**NB:** Haven't tested the above yet but it should give you at least some direction on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post such a great step-by-step explained solution. I tested your final aggregate, and this is what the result looks like: http://i654.photobucket.com/albums/uu261/muscaiu/2017-05-09_16h49_06_zpsazgltwdo.png?t=1494251713 It's doing something only to the 2-nd Object, but it's not permanent.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative using `$substrCP` and `$concat` as expression to `$map`.

Of course you will need the `$toUpper` and his brother in crime `$toLower` to convert the string to uppercase or lowercase

```
db.collection.aggregate([
       {
          "$addFields": {
             "username": {
                "$reduce": {
                   "input": {
                      "$map": {
                         "input": {
                            "$split": [
                               "$username",
                               " "
                            ]
                         },
                         "in": {
                            "$concat": [
                               {
                                  "$toUpper": {
                                     "$substrCP": [
                                        "$$this",
                                        0,
                                        1
                                     ]
                                  }
                               },
                               {
                                  "$toLower": {
                                     "$substrCP": [
                                        "$$this",
                                        1,
                                        { "$strLenCP": "$$this" }
                                     ]
                                  }
                               }
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "initialValue": "",
                   "in": {
                      "$concat": [
                         "$$value",
                         " ",
                         "$$this"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hey i tested your solution, and it's saying `Fetched 0 record(s)`

Comment: @CristianMuscalu perhaps you are not using the right collection